# How do I make the content of a folder visible directly in a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I don't like having all the content of my repo into a folder. How can I put its content directly at the root?

Here is what the repo looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the *carrot-market* folder is at the root of your repository. If you want the content of it to be at the root, you need to:

1. Create a new branch with `git checkout -b my_new_branch` (doing stuff in a new branch in case something goes wrong)
2. Move the content of *carrot-market* out of it, at the root of the repo with `git mv carrot-market/* .`
3. Delete the *carrot-market* folder
4. Commit all the changes with `git commit -a -m "Put files from carrot-market folder directly at the root"`
5. Push your changes with `git push -u origin my_new_branch` (assuming the remote is called *origin*)

Now, if everything looks the way you want in your new branch, you can merge it to your main branch.